# how can I change (0,0) position from left upper corner to right upper corner in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to set a Persian or an Arabic word on a picture !my code is:

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
text = str(input())
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
img = Image.open("d:\\input.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
# font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)
font = ImageFont.truetype("d:\\BTitrBd.ttf", 60)
# draw.text((x, y),"Sample Text",(r,g,b))
draw.text((1770, 195),bidi_text,(0,0,0),font=font)
img.save('d:\\output.jpg')
img.show()
```

This code works OK. But the position that my text added to picture calculates from left upper corner and from where I want to add a right to left sentence,it does not word well.For example I want to set "سلام" to position (x,y),but with this code,character "م" sets on that position where I am going to set character "س"there.
So how can I change (0,0) position from left upper corner to right upper corner?

Comment: Is the problem only that the text appears at the wrong position, or is it also not correctly written from right to left?

Comment: yes!only that the text appears at the wrong position.